# Android: understanding reasons of device crash

Tags: android, crash, logcat

The device I use for development process self-restarts once in a while. It happens **when it is not in use** - just lying quietly on the table not even connected to a computer.

I'm worried that this may (or may not - I don't know) be connected to my app problems.

**Question**: How can I get info on crash reasons after device restart? 
(Logcat can't get anything after restart).

Thanks

Comment: Test your app using Google Alpha or Beta staging, report each time crash happened. You will got all your crashes logs over the developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log to a file or rest web service.

Comment: What should I log? It may be some uncaught exception, some other software's or even a hardware problem.

Comment: Start putting a log entry in all your OnCreate methods. With this, you know what is the last fragment or activity called before app crashs